# Visual Studio Code creates multiple instances on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am using Visual Studio Code version 1.1.1 on 64-bit Windows 7 OS.

Whenever I start VS Code, it creates multiple instances. Is this happening for everyone? Any problem with my setup?

**Note:** I am only using Angular 2 with TypeScript in VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a user setting:

> The window.openFilesInNewWindow setting controls if files should open
>   in a new window instead of reusing an existing VS Code instance. By
>   default, VS Code will open a new window when you double-click on a
>   file outside VS Code or open a file from the command line. Set this to
>   false to reuse the last active instance of VS Code and open files in
>   there.

Go to File/Preferences/User settings.

The default value (on the left pane) is:

```
// When enabled, will open files in a new window instead of reusing an existing instance. 
"window.openFilesInNewWindow": true
```

To change the setting, insert the following line in your custom settings (right pane).

```
{

    "window.openFilesInNewWindow": false
}
```

You can find full details on these settings [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace).